# How to get data values from JobDataMap?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a JobDataMap Object

```
JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
String[] key = dataMap.getKeys();
```

key is **foo** as String,
key is **data** data have a json like this=> `{"abc":"xyz","pqr":"123wer"}`.
I want to get values from data object and set to String.

For eg: `String abc = data.abc;` Here I want to set value from data.

How do I get values from data object? Please help me....

Comment: Have a look at [the JavaDocs of `JobDataMap`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html), you either cannot get a `String` value (only other data types) or — since `JobDataMap implements Map<String, Object>` — you can try `String dataValue = dataMap.get("foo").toString()` in case the object is supporting a proper `toString()` method.

Comment: Here we can get all values like this => for (Entry<String, Object> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
      if(entry.getKey() == "data"){
        LOG.info("Job data: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }  but how  we get values from entry.getValue()(json data) ?

Comment: If you want to decode the JSON data, use a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or any other. There are many of them…

Comment: Hey i got it... Thanks dude
String dataValue = dataMap.get("data").toString();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataValue);
String abc = (String) json.get("abc");

Comment: Very good, could you please edit the solution into your question or answer your question yourself (if possible, may be not).

Answer (score 0):

```
solution is below:   

  String dataValue = dataMap.get("data").toString();

     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 

     JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataValue);
     or we can also use objectMapper instead JSONParser.

     String abc = (String) json.get("abc")
```